# Preferences updates just once

Tags: java, android

I've made a small app with a main activity and a preference activity. This is the PrefsActivity:

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

Then I trigger the Preference activity from the main activity via menu and ask to set the volume to 0 if the checkbox is selected:

This is the whole main activity:

```
package com.stressedmanasoft.clickcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.preference.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView counter;
MediaPlayer clicksnd;
MediaPlayer resetsnd;
int x=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Counter);
    clicksnd = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clicksnd);
    resetsnd = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.resetsnd);

    final TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Count);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bohemian_typewriter.ttf");
    count.setTypeface(face);
    count.setText(""+x);

    final Button countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CountButton);
    countButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicksnd.start();
            x = x+1;
            count.setText(""+x);
        }
    });

    final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetsnd.start();
            x = 0;
            count.setText(""+x);
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(myPreference.getBoolean("checkBox", true)) {
        clicksnd.setVolume(0, 0);}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrefsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(myPreference.getBoolean("checkBox", true)) {
    clicksnd.setVolume(0, 0);
    }

}

}
```

When I start the app, the audio is ON and the checkbox is NOT checked. If I check it, the audio turns OFF as expected, but if I uncheck it the audio remains OFF. Why?

Should I add a Listener?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(myPreference.getBoolean("checkBox", true)) {
        clicksnd.setVolume(0, 0);
    } else {
        clicksnd.setVolume(100, 100);
    }
}
```

The only difference is that it's the `onResume()` you'll be overriding, instead of the `onStart()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried but still no luck. :(

Comment: Well, you'll have to give us the whole `Activity` if we are to be able to help you. :)

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but I really doubt it. I mean, what's `clicksnd` declared as, and where is it assigned a value? Where's the `onCreate()`? I can't see 'em in the code you've posted. :)

Comment: I've edited the code in the question. Now it contains the whole activity. Sorry for that, I'm new to the website. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer above, let me know if it works as expected to.

Comment: Mmmmh, nope. From the preferences activity I go back to the main one pressing the back button. Every time I made a change in the Prefs activity, it's saved automatically and sent to the SharedPreferences instance, right? What if I reload the preferences in the main activity?